# Slow SQL query because of ORDER BY not using index

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance

I've got this query:

```
SELECT cl.title, cl.URL, cl.ID AS ad_id, cl.cat_id, cl.price, cs.name AS cat_name, pix.file_name, area.area_name 
FROM classifieds cl 
FORCE INDEX (advertiser_id) 
INNER JOIN classifieds_pix pix ON cl.ID = pix.classified_id 
INNER JOIN cat_names_sub cs ON cl.cat_id = cs.ID 
INNER JOIN zip_codes zip ON cl.zip_id = zip.zip_id 
INNER JOIN area_names area ON zip.area_id = area.id 
WHERE cl.confirmed = 1 AND cl.price != '' AND cl.country = 'de' 
GROUP BY cl.advertiser_id
ORDER BY cl.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

It takes > 1 sec when `classifieds` contains 168k rows, which is too long. `FORCE INDEX (advertiser_id)` allowed me to bring it down to 0.00x secs without the `ORDER BY` clause. The `timestamp` column is indexed, too, and I tried adding `FORCE INDEX (timestamp)`, but it didn't help.

`EXPLAIN` says `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort` on the first `SELECT` from the `classifieds` table - which obviously causes the performance issue.

Can you help me out on this one?

Thanks in advance!

PS: The purpose of this query is to get the 5 latest classifieds (including some additional information such as picture, category, zip code and area name). Furthermore, only one classified should be shown per advertiser. Can this be so hard?

PPS: I tried to pin the problem down as much as possible and ended up with this query:

```
SELECT cl.title
FROM classifieds cl
GROUP BY cl.advertiser_id
ORDER BY cl.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 5
```

It takes incredible 23 secs! With `FORCE INDEX (advertiser_id)` I can take it to 1 sec. If I remove either the GROUP BY or the ORDER BY, it goes down to 0.0003 secs.

Something's gotta be wrong with my tables/indexes? I should not need `FORCE INDEX` (btw: `USE INDEX` doesn't work - I need to force it!) and it shouldn't take that long!

Comment: I'm confused by what it means to do your SELECT in the context of the GROUP BY cl.advertiser_id.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` makes sure only one classified per advertiser is selected.

Comment: can you post your query explain plan, show indexes from <all tables in your query>, show create table <all tables in your query> - just throw it all into http://pastie.org/ to save space then we might be able to help - tia

Comment: I've updated the post to include the data you requested.

Comment: What is the basis of the timestamp.  Just when last "touched", or is that the indicator of the most recent ad posted by an advertiser?  Or, is there another "ID" key (sequentially maybe) associated with the lastest ad for an advertiser.  If multiple ads are listed but scheduled for future times, you might not want that if you are concerned only about upcoming, or within a given time range... can sigificantly help / impact the query.

Comment: The timestamp is the creation date of the advert - there are no scheduled adverts, all adverts are published immediately. The only filtering I need is done in the WHERE clause of the query I at the top of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way of avoiding the fact that sorting 168k rows is going to take some doing, regardless of indexing.  It's one thing to locate rows in your table by an index, but once it's found them the engine still has to sort them.

1s seems pretty reasonable to me btw.

(Removed edit suggesting alternative indexes; OP tried this with no success)

Comment: Doesn't `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort` indicate something is not as optimized as it could/should be?

Comment: @eWolf - Correction, Using filesort does not mean slow

Comment: I was referring more to the temporary table - the query profile shows that `Copying to tmp table` takes 1.205894 secs which is by far the longest part.

Comment: @eWolf - because of the group by, remove it and try again

Comment: -1, You defeat your own logic in the first sentence. Let me reverse it - 'I think there is a way of avoiding sorting of 168M (or k, regardless) records if there is an index that can be used for both filtering and retrieving the records in order'. You afterwards admit this possibility with the composite index.

Comment: @Unreason - you're quite right, but I would argue the answer as a whole, including the clearly marked edit, shows a coherent line of thought which may help the OP

Comment: @Brian, I would argue that a part of the answer is definitively misleading. If you edit or state in the answer that the first part is wrong I'll be happy to remove downvote.

Comment: @Brian I tried adding an additional index (both advertiser_id, timestamp and timestamp, advertiser_id) and, unfortunately, it didn't help.. Do you have any other suggestions? Btw: I edited my original post, make sure to read the PS sections.

Comment: Ah well; maybe it's true you simply can't improve the speed of the sort.  Sorting 168k records just to get the top 5 is not very efficient though, I'd recommend having a major rethink of what's best attempted here, e.g. just select the top newest timestamps, whichever advertiser they happen to belong to?

Answer (score 2):

Although slightly restructured, I would consider looking at your where clause on your classifieds table and see if that has any indexes to utilize... Such as by confirmed, price, country.  Whichever is available with the lowest probable record counts I would list first -- probably put country first, then confirmed.  Addiitonally, remove the group by.  You have no aggregation functions associated to the query.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      cl.title, 
      cl.URL, 
      cl.ID AS ad_id, 
      cl.cat_id, 
      cl.price, 
      cs.name AS cat_name, 
      pix.file_name, 
      area.area_name  
   FROM 
      ( select clMax.advertiser_id, 
               max( clMax.TimeStamp ) as AdvMaxTime
           from findix.classifieds clMax
           where  clMax.confirmed = 1 
              AND clMax.price != '' 
              AND clMax.country = 'de'  
           group by 1
           order by 2 desc
           limit 5 ) clQualified,
      findix.classifieds cl,
      findix.classifieds_pix pix,
      findix.cat_names_sub cs,
      findix.zip_codes zip,
      findix.area_names area
   WHERE
          clQualified.advertiser_id = cl.advertiser_id
      AND clQualified.AdvMaxTime = cl.timestamp;
      AND cl.ID = pix.classified_id  
      AND cl.cat_id = cs.ID 
      AND cl.zip_id = zip.zip_id  
      AND zip.area_id = area.id
```

By changing to match your qualification, I've move that to an inner pre-query that gets per advertiser that qualifies the criteria, gets the maximum timestamp entry orders most recent and limits to 5 as the first "table" being queried for the result set.  From that, I have 5 records to join to the other tables which should be almost instantaneous as you are encountering.

Comment: +1 because I wondered about the GROUP BY too, but couldn't put my finger on why it was troubling me.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is necessary to make each advertiser_id unique in the result - read the latest edits I made to my original post for more details.

Comment: @eWolf, I've revised based on your feedback... It should help.

Comment: @eWolf, did this query finally get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed a multi index?

Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX adv_tt ON classifieds ( advertiser_id , `timestamp` );
```

Or even this:

```
CREATE INDEX adv_tt ON classifieds 
( confirmed , price , country , advertiser_id , `timestamp` );
```

PS: I don't know if MySQL apply first the GROUP BY or the ORDER BY, if it's first the ORDER BY, you have to change the columns order in the INDEX ( ... `timestamp` , advertiser_id )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the statistics on the table?

Comment: Do you mean `ANALYZE TABLE`? Yes, I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is F*ed up.. You have `GROUP BY cl.advertiser_id` but also `ORDER BY cl.timestamp` DESC
timestamp is not in the `Group BY` This shouldn't be allowed!

Why do you have a `Group BY` at All!! 
Take it out. Remove your `force index.` 
Then fix your code so it doesn't have any dups, that is not what group by is for.

Edit:
Try

```
SELECT cl.title, cl.URL, cl.ID AS ad_id, cl.cat_id, cl.price, cl.timestamp
cs.name AS cat_name, pix.file_name, area.area_name 
FROM findix.classifieds cl 
INNER JOIN findix.classifieds_pix pix ON cl.ID = pix.classified_id 
INNER JOIN findix.cat_names_sub cs ON cl.cat_id = cs.ID 
INNER JOIN findix.zip_codes zip ON cl.zip_id = zip.zip_id 
INNER JOIN findix.area_names area ON zip.area_id = area.id 
WHERE cl.confirmed = 1 AND cl.price != '' AND cl.country = 'de' 
ORDER BY cl.timestamp DESC
```

or

```
SELECT cl.advertiser_id,cl.title, cl.URL, cl.ID AS ad_id, cl.cat_id, cl.price, cl.timestamp
max(cs.name) AS cat_name, max(pix.file_name) as file_name, max(area.area_name) as area.area_name
FROM findix.classifieds cl 
INNER JOIN findix.classifieds_pix pix ON cl.ID = pix.classified_id 
INNER JOIN findix.cat_names_sub cs ON cl.cat_id = cs.ID 
INNER JOIN findix.zip_codes zip ON cl.zip_id = zip.zip_id 
INNER JOIN findix.area_names area ON zip.area_id = area.id 
WHERE cl.confirmed = 1 AND cl.price != '' AND cl.country = 'de' 
Group By cl.advertiser_id,cl.title, cl.URL, cl.ID AS ad_id, cl.cat_id, cl.price, cl.timestamp
ORDER BY cl.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is supposed to select only one classified per advertiser - is this the wrong approach to do this?

Comment: Id there are 4 diffident values in the subtables how does the query know which one to take? (See my edit).

Comment: Your 1st query runs pretty slow (.7 secs). EXPLAIN says `Using temporary; Using filesort`. The second one takes 1 sec, and also uses a temporary table and filesort.

Comment: Check out the latest edit to my original post. I highly suspect it's something with my indexes/tables.